# Temporary job agency in Berlin, Germany to receive salary from USA

Tags: usa, germany, salary

I would like to know if there is some sort of "temporary job agency" in Berlin, Germany (not too sure if that is the correct term) that could sort out the wage payment from the USA.

My wife is currently a PhD student in a US university who receives salary per month as she is employed by the university to do some projects. As she is going to live with me in Germany, she could not receive the salary in USD directly while she is not living in USA. Her advisor suggested finding a temporary job agency in Germany so that the university could transfer the salary to this agency and my wife will then be "employed" by this agency to get her monthly salary in Euro (minus the fee, taxes, and health insurance, etc).

I have been looking for this type of company that can do that but until now I could not find any information about this. Is this even possible or legal in Germany? If so, where could I find it?

Comment: What's your wife's citizenship.

Comment: @chx she's Indonesian

Comment: I suggest this is called payroll company